# How to send data to Flask via AJAX?

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I'm making small web project based on Flask. And I have to send some data to Flask, but I don't know how to do it. I tried different ways, tried to use JSON, but I don't know how to work with it. Maybe someone can share working piece of code with me or help by explaining what I have to do?

```
new_freq = $('#input').val() //value I want to send 
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/set_freq', 
    type: 'POST', 
    data: ,
    success: function(response){ 
        $('#main').text(response) 
    } 
})
```

Comment: Your javascript looks essentially fine, what's your code like on the flask side?

Comment: @AlexHall actually I don't know what to put in Flask code ;(

Comment: Google "python flask post example"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
new_freq = $('#input').val() //value I want to send 
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/set_freq', 
    type: 'POST', 
    data: new_freq,
    success: function(response){ 
        $('#main').text(response) 
    } 
})
```

in Flask

```
new_freq = request.get_data()
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but also I have to decode data from bytes after I accepted it

Comment: Flask has many different methods to get the post value. use request.get_data() to get raw value. use request.args() to get params in url like `xxx.com/xxx?a=1`, use request.form() to get the data post in form. It depends on how you send the data to flask.

Answer (score 2):

In the ajax code use a dictionary instead :

```
data: {
  'new_freq': new_freqd  //  to the GET parameters
},
```

in your app views, to retrieve it use :

```
new_freq = request.args.get('new_freq')
```

Answer (score 1):

Flask 2.0.2

Script:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/set_freq',
        data: {'new_freq':new_freq},
        type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

Controller:

```
@app.route("/set_freq", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def conf_services():
    if request.method == "POST":
        app.logger.warning(request.values.get('new_freq'))
    return render_template('index.html')
```