# how can i pass these javascript variables i.e coordinates to my flask

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

I am not able to pass the coordinates to my flask

i have no idea how to pass javascript variables

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

Latitude: 13.8863984
Longitude: 77.44150069999999

Comment: By making a request to flask. E.g. with a URL (data embedded in url), with a form, with a Ajax (JSON, etc.). Probably you want some answer back, so you need to think which kind, before to choose the method. But this is basic. You need to look tutorial. With answer here you will not learn correctly [complete, tricks, etc. ] (and quickly)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you might want to use AJAX to send data to flask. This would be useful if you wanted to process the latitude and longitude data in flask and do something with it. Here is a link to another StackOverflow question which contains info on how to do this: [How to send data to Flask via AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41323679/how-to-send-data-to-flask-via-ajax)

Answer (score -1):

Use [geocoder](https://github.com/DenisCarriere/geocoder) instead, it is realy simple.

```
import geocoder as gc
g = gc.ip('me') #ip is also accepted here
print(g.latlng)
```